# What is wrong with this program for scanning a file and returning number of lines/paragraphs/words?

Tags: c, loops, infinite

I wrote this program to accept a file and scan the number of lines, paragraphs, and words in the file.

The problem is, it does not stop scanning, ever.  It never comes out of the while (nextChar!='\n') loop.  So the functions processBlank and copyText never stop running.  It never hits the EOF.

I am unsure how to proceed.  I am at a loss for a solution so any help is appreciated :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void initialize(int *p1,int *p2,int *p3,int *p4)
{
    *p1=0;
    *p2=0;
    *p3=0;
    *p4=0;
}

void processBlank(char *nextChar,int *wordsinLine,FILE *ctPtr)
{
    while (*nextChar==' ')
    {
        printf("%c",*nextChar);
        *nextChar=fgetc(ctPtr);
    }
    *wordsinLine+=1;
}

void copyText(char *nextChar,FILE *ctPtr)
{
    while (*nextChar!=' ')
    {
        printf("%c",*nextChar);
        *nextChar=fgetc(ctPtr);
    }
}

void updateCount(int *numWords,int *wordsinLine,int *numParagraphs,int *numLines)
{
    *numWords+=*wordsinLine;
    if (*wordsinLine==0)
        *numParagraphs+=1;
    *wordsinLine=0;
    *numLines+=1;
}

void printTotal(int numWords,int numLines,int numParagraphs)
{
    printf("\n\n\n\nTotal number of words is: %d\n\n",numWords);
    printf("Total number of lines is: %d\n\n",numLines);
    printf("Total number of paragraphs is: %d\n\n\n\n",numParagraphs);
}

void main()
{
    int numWords,numLines,numParagraphs,wordsinLine;
    initialize(&numWords,&numLines,&numParagraphs,&wordsinLine);
    FILE *ctPtr;
    char nextChar;
    if ((ctPtr=fopen("Q2read.txt", "r"))==NULL)
        printf("File could not be opened\n");
    else
    {
        nextChar=fgetc(ctPtr);
        while (nextChar!=feof(ctPtr))
        {

            while (nextChar!='\n')
            {
                processBlank(&nextChar,&wordsinLine,ctPtr);
                copyText(&nextChar,ctPtr);
            }
            updateCount(&numWords,&wordsinLine,&numParagraphs,&numLines);
        }
        printTotal(numWords,numLines,numParagraphs);
        fclose(ctPtr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Major: Change `nextChar!=feof(ctPtr)` to `nextChar != EOF`.
   `feof()` return "nonzero if and only if the end-of-file indicator is
   set"
   `EOF` is some negative number.
   2 different things - not well comparable.
2. Minor: change `void main()` to `int main(void)`
3. Minor Change `char nextChar` to `int nextChar`  (also related function calls.)
4. Major: `copyText()`: change to `while (*nextChar != ' ' && *nextChar != EOF) {`
5. In `main()` change to  `while (nextChar != '\n' && nextChar != EOF) {`  Add EOF test.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Changing these things does not fix the error, although I have changed them.  Thanks!

Comment: Well it actually exits the while loop now!  And it gives me an output, the only problem is that it does not give the correct amount of lines, paragraphs, and words.   But I will keep trying.  Thanks for the help Chux.   It is telling me there is only one line in the entire document (there are actually 100).. So I believe it is using the EOF condition to exit the while loop, and it is not actually using the !='\n' condition at all

Comment: I see a problem.   If I add an if statement in copyText() or processBlank() that says printf HERE!!!!! when nextChar is \n, I see that msg at every space.  Which tells me, even though I have the condition to not enter those functions when nextChar = \n , it is still getting into those loops and incrementing past \n, so the while loop in main never sees it.  How can I break the function and return to main during a while loop inside copyText()  if nextChar = \n?

Comment: Ideas: 1) Certain code does not need the double while loop in `main()` 2) In `processBlank()` and `copyText()`, think you want something like `while (isblank(*nextChar))`.

Comment: Point 3 is a mayor one: if `nextChar` is of type `char` it simply can't be `EOF`.

Comment: @cmaster Agree #3 is important.  Many (most?) `char` are signed and `EOF` is often `-1`, thus such a `char` can have the same _value_ as `EOF`.  Because of this, unfortunately, `EOF` apparently "works".  Of course, this is a problem as `fgetc()` returns an `unsigned char` and `EOF` and `char` is not always signed.  Thus `char` cannot _distinctly_ represent all `char` and `EOF`.

Answer (score 0):

`fgetc()` returns an int, and `EOF` is usually -1. Declare nextChar as an int and check it against `EOF` (not `feof()`; `feof()` is a function that tests a stream for eof)

You could instead check `feof(stream) != 0` (say with `if (feof(stream))`)  to see if you are at EOF, but I think just checking the return value of `fgetc()` is nicer.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply!  I tried your suggestion and the code runs the exact same as it did as I posted it.  I assume it would see the end of file, if only it could get out of the nested while loop.  it appears that nextChar!='\n' is never false.  I also tried adding while (nextChar!=10) (ascii code for new line) also doesn't exit the loop

Comment: Do not agree with "check feof(stream) > 0".  `feof` function returns nonzero at end-of-file, not necessarily a positive number.  Suggest instead `if (feof(stream))`.

Comment: @chux I agree and will update my answer. I was trying to avoid matching -1, (my man page for feof seems to think that that could indicate an error), but ignoring the error and continuing doesn't make much sense either

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading your file byte by byte, (INCREDIBLY SLOW), look up the `fgets()` function.  That will get a whole LINE of text for you, and then you can process it from there.  It DOES take a max string length, so if you use something reasonable, like 1024, ALWAYS make sure you check your string for a newline, if it is NOT in the string, you need to read AGAIN, and append, but before you do, check to see if you ARE in fact at EOF, as a lot of files just might not HAVE that final `\n`, or `\r\n`, or `\r`, or whatever craziness the OS you are using uses...

Comment: Concerning performance difference of `fgets()` vs `fgetc()`, any benchmarks to support "INCREDIBLY SLOW"?

Comment: I don't have any benchmarks handy, but imagine this.  Say you are reading a very large file, 1 megabyte, with an average line length of 1024 chars.  That means you are going to call that function 1024 times for EVERY LINE in the file (on average), which in itself, doesn't seem like a big deal, because most of the file will PROBABLY be loaded into the file cache anyway.  However, just the act of calling a function in C takes time.  Things have to be pushed to the stack, popped, then executed, then returned.  fgets() does this all in ONE function call.  See the difference?

Comment: @chux Give the function call overhead ten nanoseconds (which is quite reasonable), and you have an overhead of ten seconds for reading a gigabyte byte by byte. That's not a big issue, but it's worth not getting into the habit to do.

Comment: There is an even better function to use: `getline()`. Part of the POSIX-2008 standard, it really gets the whole line, allocating sufficient space for it along the way. Which avoids a lot of headaches with buffer limits.

Comment: @cmaster I have seen implementations of `fgets()` which itself was a series of calls to `fgetc()`, thus comparing the performance of 1 `fgets()` vs. 1024 `fgetc()` from a theoretical view may yield a _wide_ range of answers concerning how one is faster.  Premature optimization is not a good habit.  The order of magnitude is the same with either approach. Since LarryF said "INCREDIBLY SLOW", I was hoping to see some test data to quantify the degree of performance difference.

Comment: @chux Well, if `fgets()` is implemented using `fgetc()`, that implementation either relies on compiler inlining, or it is a mediocre implementation of `fgets()`. True, in many cases people won't recognize the difference, but it's there and should be avoided in a quality implementation of the standard C library. Of course, many such implementations are suboptimal (if not all of them), but that shouldn't be an excuse to write application code that is clearly, up front suboptimal. Once you've written those `fgetc()` calls it's more difficult to replace them than avoiding them in the first place.